# Geth Sent the Transaction to the Wrong Address?

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts

I just followed the [guide](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Sending-ether), and I made the same mistake as someone else, found [here](https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/4743/eth-sent-to-wrong-address-how-1-eth-reward).

Essentially if you use the syntax `to:eth.accounts[0xXXXXXX....]` instead of `to:"0xXXXXXX...."`, Geth will create its own, random address, and sent it to there. It would be nice if this was explicitly mentioned in the guide.

Is there a fix for this? I did not type in the address that the transaction was sent to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eth.accounts` returns an array with all of your accounts, and you access the elements of an array by their index, i.e. `eth.accounts[0]` to get your first account. In your example you are using an address as an index, and in Javascript, indexing an array with a faulty index returns undefined.

So your transaction was created without a `to` value and any such transaction creates a new smart contract (at a randomly generated address) with the code you give it in the `data` value (which was nothing in this case).

I'm afraid that there is no fix that will bring your ether back, at least to my knowledge

Comment: that was the last time i used eth. next altcoin, please.